# How do I filter an array of objects with MongoDB Object IDs based on another array of Object IDs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of movies pulled from MongoDB, named movieList:

```
[
  {
    movie: {
      _id: 5fde62aa0cec1598fda103ac,
      title: 'Wander'
    },
    status: 2
  },
  {
    movie: {
      _id: 5fde62930cec1598fd9d426c,
      title: 'Mulan'
    },
    status: 1
  },
  {
    movie: {
      _id: 5fde62a10cec1598fd9f9222,
      title: 'Greenland'
    },
    status: 0
  }
]
```

And I have an array of movie Object IDs (not strings), named removeMovies:

```
[
  5fde62a20cec1598fd9fa275,
  5fde62a30cec1598fd9fec86,
  5fde62a50cec1598fda034cf,
  5fde62a50cec1598fda03f24,
  5fde62930cec1598fd9d426c
]
```

The way that I would normally filter (if these were strings or numbers, as opposed to Object IDs) returns an empty array:

```
const filteredMovieList = movieList.filter((movie) => {
  return removeMovies.includes(movie.movie._id)
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean movie Object IDs are not strings? what type are they then?

Comment: Excellent question @DanOswalt!!!  They are an array of Object IDs from MongoDB that I did not run toString() on.  Are they objects? Console.log() prints them out as I have shown above, not wrapped in " " as would be the case with strings, I assume.

Comment: oh I see. yeah they're objects, i see in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you can use `toString` and map the removeMovies objects to those strings first:

```
const filteredMovieList = movieList.filter((movie) => {
  return removeMovies
    .map(movieId => movieId.toString())
    .includes(movie.movie._id.toString())
})
```

Looking more closely as https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/, I think you could use `str` property also.

```
const filteredMovieList = movieList.filter((movie) => {
  return removeMovies
    .map(movieId => movieId.str)
    .includes(movie.movie._id.str)
})
```

Comment: The toString() version worked, but gave me the opposite of what I needed. So I broke it apart to add a !, which did the trick:
`
const filteredMovieList = movieList.filter((movie) => {
  const movieIdsAsStrings = removeMovies.map((movieId) => movieId.toString())
  const movies = !movieIdsAsStrings.includes(movie.movie._id.toString())
  return movies
})
`

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is to cast the both objectId to a string, an example to do that:

```
const filteredMovieList = movieList.filter((movie) => {
  return removeMovies.filter(rmMovie =>  String(rmMovie) == String(movie._id)).length 
    == 0 ? false : true  
  })
```